# Why is it that when I include the <GlobalProvider> component, it can't be rendered?

Tags: reactjs

here the code

index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.js';
import GlobalStyle from './styles/GlobalStyle.js'
import { GlobalProvider } from './context/globalContext.js';


ReactDOM.render(
    <React.Fragment>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <GlobalProvider>
            <App />
        </GlobalProvider>
    </React.Fragment>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

here a globalContext.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/"

const GlobalContext = React.createContext()

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [income, setIncome] = useState([])
    const [expense, setExpense] = useState([])
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    const addIncome = async (income) => {
        const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}income`)
        .catch((err) => {
            setError(err.response.body.message)
        })
    }

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider
            value={`hello`}
        >
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => {
    return useContext(GlobalContext)
}
```

Why is it that when I include the  component, it can't be rendered?

I'm not sure why, and there are no error messages either.

i want it rendered like before

Comment: Whats the error you are seeing? Also, add the code for `GlobalProvider`.

Comment: no error message

Comment: Any error in your browser console?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

no details about that error

Comment: How are you running this app? Also share the `package.json`

Comment: maybe from axios? cuz i try to delete an axios, its rendered again, but just a sec

Comment: Remove the `axios` import and check if its works.

Comment: it works if i remove an axios,

but is there an alternative other than using Axios if I were to remove it?

Comment: You can use the `fetch` which is already available in browsers. So nothing to install. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Whats the version of your `axios` by the way? If its less than `1.0.0`, can you update it to the latest version?

Comment: i use `1.4.0` version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `axios` with `fetch` api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

There are already a few reported cases of this issue in `axios` repo: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22Cannot+use+import+statement%22

As long as your use-cases are simple, you can use `fetch`. `fetch` comes in all browsers, and as such, you dont have to install any package to use it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the error might be the fact that you are not passing the `income`, `expense`, and error states to the `GlobalContext.Provider` component. You can try updating the value prop of the `GlobalContext.Provider´ to an object that contains these states and the ´addIncome´ function. Like this:

```
<GlobalContext.Provider
  value={{
    income,
    setIncome,
    expense,
    setExpense,
    error,
    setError,
    addIncome
  }}
>
  {children}
</GlobalContext.Provider>
```

Then, in your App component or any other component that needs these states and functions, you can use the `useGlobalContext` hook to consume the context:

```
import { useGlobalContext } from './context/globalContext.js';

function MyComponent() {
  const { income, expense, error, addIncome } = useGlobalContext();

  // ...
}
```

Hope this helps.